# How to split a string into numbers?

Tags: c#, string

How can I split the following string in C#?

```
11213,334990829,2234,
```

I want to store each string (comma delimited) in a variable:
e.g.

```
Number1 = 11213
Number2 = 334990829
Number3 = 2234
```

Also, a max of 4 numeric strings would be present and if the string has less than 4 numeric strings than there will be a "," at the end of the string

For e.g: if there were two numeric strings, it would display `12121,43222,`

Comment: The word "concatenate" means to put pieces together. You're talking about taking one string and breaking it onto separate strings. See String.Split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] numbers = "11213,334990829,2234,".Split(',');
```